# Splitting polylines using regions with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, polygon, postgis-1.5

I was wondering if it is possible to split a polyline on polygon boundaries (regions) in PostGIS, the picture below is of what we have at the moment and shows where I need the polylines split:

[image]

Let's call the regions `road_blocks` and the lines `road_cl`

If you can copy the data from the `road_block` under the newly created polyline to the new polyline that would be a real bonus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE new_road_cl AS
  SELECT ST_Intersection(r.geom, b.geom) AS geom,
         b.attr1, b.attr2, b.attr3,
         r.attr1, r.attr2, r.attr3
  FROM road_blocks b, road_cl r
  WHERE ST_Intersects(r.geom, b.geom);
```

Comment: Thanks but I seem to get this when I run it: 
`TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (397766 6.83237e+006, 397769 6.83237e+006) and LINESTRING (397767 6.83238e+006, 397766 6.83237e+006) at 397766 6.83237e+006`

Comment: Just ran it on a single road, seems like there is some malformed data somewhere.

Comment: +1 Nice. Isn't `the_geom` not `geom`, the default geometry field name?

Answer (score 2):

Nathan,

1) Make sure your geometry is valid - invalid geometries are a major cause of these kind of errors.
SELECT ST_IsValid(geom);

2) Which version of geos are you running? Do a

SELECT postgis_full_version();

GEOS 3.2+ runs into fewer of these topological exception issues.

To Adam -
Paul decided one day he was too lazy to type the_geom :)  -- so he proclaimed "from now on 
the default will be -- geom".  We all stamped our feet and said -- NO until 2.0

So geog is default for geography and geom will be the default in 2.0 for geometry.